# Does an LMDB reader get the latest view of the database if the writer is updating constantly?

Tags: lmdb

I am using LMDB database.
I have a writer and multiple readers. One of the readers is transient and the other is long running which does an open once and reads multiple times. The transient reader works fine, but the read from the long running sometimes gives stale data and sometimes fails.

Are the reads in LMDB reader represent the latest view of the database always?
Does the reader have to do update() or something to get the latest view?

Answer (score 0):

LMDB is copy on write DB and read transaction locks pages it touches. So, if you have an open long running read transaction it will only see the older pages in general. Also, long running transaction prevents writer from being able to reuse locked pages so the DB will be forced to allocate new pages and as result DB will grow much faster.

LMDB isn't designed to have long running transaction and having them will lead to issues. You need to try and keep your transactions as short as possible. If you do need to have a long running transaction, it might be better to look for an alternative DB as it most likely won't work well with LMDB.

Comment: In the long running process for every read we are opening a transaction

Comment: If you're opening new read transaction for every read then every new transaction should see the latest snapshot of data. If you're opening LMDB from different OS processes, need to make sure certain flags are the same. For example MDB_WRITEMAP flag either needs to be use everywhere or not at all. - http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/group__mdb.html#ga32a193c6bf4d7d5c5d579e71f22e9340